# GLFW high GPU usage

Tags: java, kotlin, lwjgl, glfw

Even for this simple program that draws a blank screen, GLFW is using about 15% of the GPU according to windows task manager. Is there a problem or is GPU usage in task manager misleading? I've noticed that JavaFX and swing applications have very little GPU usage in comparison.

```
fun main() {
    GLFW.glfwInit()

    val window = GLFW.glfwCreateWindow(1920, 1080, "window", 0, 0)

    GLFW.glfwMakeContextCurrent(window)

    GLFW.glfwSwapInterval(1)

    GL.createCapabilities()

    while(!GLFW.glfwWindowShouldClose(window)) {
        GL46C.glClear(GL46C.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT)

        GLFW.glfwPollEvents()

        GLFW.glfwSwapBuffers(window)
    }

    GLFW.glfwTerminate()
}
```

Comment: If you aren't using Vsync or a fixed frame rate, it is going to draw frames as fast as it possibly can, so even the simplest of scenes will use a significant amount of GPU.

Comment: glfwSwapInterval(1) enables vsync. This was running at 60fps. I didn't expect clearing and swapping the buffer to be so expensive.

Comment: You should measure if v-sync actually is enabled. There's been some problems with `glfwSwapInterval`, especially on MacOS. There's an [open issue](https://github.com/glfw/glfw/issues/2249) for MacOS on Github.